# List/Array with optionals

Tags: scala, monads, option-type

Which is better in practice? Having an optional List or having optional items in the list?

Currently I'm following an optional list.

List[Option[T]] or Option[List[T]]?

**Edit:**

The problem I'm running into is that i have crud operations that i'm returning optional types from. I have a situation where I have a method that does a single lookup and i want to leverage it to make a function to return a list. I'm still getting my feet wet with scala so I'm curious what the best practice is.

Example:

```
def findOne(id: Int): Option[T]
```

regardless of implementation I want to use it for something like these, but which is better? They both seem to be weird to map from. Maybe there's something i'm missing all together:

```
def find(ids: List[Int]) : Option[List[T]]
```

vs

```
def find(ids: List[Int]) : List[Option[T]]
```

Comment: Better for what? This is like asking which is better, Integer or String?

Comment: Which is more logically correct? Which type more accurately describes the result of `find`? Use the type which more accurately models the data, not which is easier to deal with.

Comment: `Optional` is a Java 8 type. `Option` is the type name in Scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retrieve several things that might exist, and it's sensible for some of them to exist and some of them to not exist, it's `List[Option[T]]` - a list of several entries, each of which is present or not. This would make sense in e.g. a "search" situation, where you want to display whichever ones exist, possibly only some of the requested things. You could implement that method as:

```
def find(ids: List[Int]) = ids map findOne
```

If you're using `Option` to represent something like an an "error" case, and you want "if any of them failed then the whole thing is a failure", then you want `Option[List[T]]` - either a complete list, or nothing at all. You could implement that, using Scalaz, as:

```
def find(ids: List[Int]) = ids traverse findOne
```

Answer (score 6):

Those two types mean very different things. `List[Option[T]]` looks like an intermediate result that would you would `flatten`. (I'd look into using `flatMap` in this case.)

The second type, `Option[List[T]]` says there may or may not be a list. This would be a good type to use when you need to distinguish between the "no result" case and the "result is an empty list" case.

I can't think of a situation where both types would make sense.

Answer (score 1):

DaoWen already got to the point regarding your considerations. 
`List[Option[T]]` doesn't even encode more information than `List[T]` without the implicit knowledge that your list of ids is in the same order than your result list.

I'd actualy favour

```
def find(ids: Seq[Int]): Seq[T]
```

or

```
def find(ids: Seq[Int]): Option[NonEmptyList[T]]
```

where NonEmptyList is a type of sequence that actually enforces being not empty, e.g. in [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/NonEmptyList.scala). Unless you really wanna point out the difference between `None` and some empty list.

Btw, you might wanna use the more general `Seq[T]` for your interface instead of `List[T]`